# Mapstruct Mapping : Return null object if all source parameters properties are null

Tags: java, object-object-mapping, mapstruct

I want the generated mapstruct mapping method to return null if all the properties referenced in @Mapping/source are null.
For exemple, I have the following mapping :

```
@Mappings({
      @Mapping(target = "id", source = "tagRecord.tagId"),
      @Mapping(target = "label", source = "tagRecord.tagLabel")
})
Tag mapToBean(TagRecord tagRecord);
```

The generated method is then :

```
public Tag mapToBean(TagRecord tagRecord) {
    if ( tagRecord == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    Tag tag_ = new Tag();

    if ( tagRecord.getTagId() != null ) {
        tag_.setId( tagRecord.getTagId() );
    }
    if ( tagRecord.getTagLabel() != null ) {
        tag_.setLabel( tagRecord.getTagLabel() );
    }

    return tag_;
}
```

Test case : TagRecord object is not null but has tagId==null and tagLibelle==null.

Current behaviour : the returned Tag object is not null, but has tagId==null and tagLibelle==null

What I actually want the generated method to do is return a null Tag object if (tagRecord.getTagId() == null && tagRecord.getTagLabel() == null).
Is it possible and how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This currently is not supported from MapStruct directly. However, you can achieve what you want the help of [`Decorators`](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#customizing-mappers-using-decorators) and you will have to manually check if all the fields are empty and return `null` instead of the object.

```
@Mapper
@DecoratedWith(TagMapperDecorator.class)
public interface TagMapper {
    @Mappings({
        @Mapping(target = "id", source = "tagId"),
        @Mapping(target = "label", source = "tagLabel")
    })
    Tag mapToBean(TagRecord tagRecord);
}


public abstract class TagMapperDecorator implements TagMapper {

    private final TagMapper delegate;

    public TagMapperDecorator(TagMapper delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public Tag mapToBean(TagRecord tagRecord) {
        Tag tag = delegate.mapToBean( tagRecord);

        if (tag != null && tag.getId() == null && tag.getLabel() == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return tag;
        }
    }
}
```

The example that I have written (the constructor) is for mappers that are with the `default` component model. If you need to use Spring or a different DI framework have a look at:

- [Decorators with Spring](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#decorators-with-spring)
- [Decorators with JSR 330](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#decorators-with-jsr-330)
- If you use CDI, then you should not use `@DecoratedWith`, but you should use [CDI Decorators](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html/decorators.html) instead

Comment: hi Filip,  is this feature added now?

Comment: Not entirely. There is a new feature added for conditional mappings, but it isn't working for method source parameters yet

Answer (score 1):

Now it is possible with, for example:

```
@BeanMapping(nullValueMappingStrategy = NullValueMappingStrategy.RETURN_DEFAULT)
```

That affects a method, to affect a whole class use with @Mapper

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. 
`nullValueMappingStrategy = RETURN_DEFAULT` only says that if the input parameter is null, then an empty object. 
If nothing is annotated or if `nullValueMappingStrategy = RETURN_NULL`, then `null` is returned when the input parameter is `null`.
However, the goal is to do the other way : return `null` when the input parameter is not `null` and all the fields are `null`.