# How to return a null from a mapper if a condition is met

Tags: spring-boot, mapstruct

I want to return null from my mapper method if a complex condition is met, but mapstruct ignores null value returned from @AfterMapping method, so How can I achieve this?

The code below has comments that demonstrate what I need

```
class User{
    String name;
    Role role;
    Date birthDate;
}
```

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
interface UserMapper{
    Inner toUser(Source source);
    /* I want to return a null user depending on a complex condition
    *  However, mapstruct ingores null value returned from the following @AfterMapping method
    * */
    
    @AfterMapping
    default User checkUser(@MappingTarget User user){
        // return null or not depending on a complex condition
        if(condition)
            return null;
        else return user;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a decorator:

Official documentation: [Customizing mappings with Decorator](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#_customizing_mappings) 
StackOverflow similar question: [mapstruct return null if condition is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43391995/mapstruct-mapping-return-null-object-if-all-source-parameters-properties-are-n)